# Jquery Border Color Toggle Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am attempting to do is change the borders on a document from blue to something different, preferably clear if anything. Any Ideas?

Current Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/NqTuv/

Why is this not working?

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#header").addClass("hover");
            $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
    };
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#header").removeClass("hover");
        $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
    };

$(".guess_box").hover(function(){
    //This is the mouseenter event handler
    $(this).addClass("my_hover");
};
function(){
    //this is the mouseleav event handel
    $(this).removeClass("my_hover");
};

};
```

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. Check your javascript console and use the JSHint button on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a complete mess! I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqTuv/1/). It should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#header").addClass("hover");
        $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#header").removeClass("hover");
        $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NqTuv/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#header").addClass("hover");
        $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#header").removeClass("hover");
    $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
  });

  $(".guess_box").hover(function(){
    //This is the mouseenter event handler
    $(this).addClass("my_hover");
  });
  $(".guess_box").mouseout(function(){
    //this is the mouseleav event handel
    $(this).removeClass("my_hover");
  });
});
```

Comment: the .hover and .mouseout is not the right way to do it. You should use .on

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle is running the script `onload`, but you also include a listener for document ready, my the time the `onload` event happens the document is already `ready`; your other issues were syntax, mostly missing closing parenthesis.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#header").addClass("hover");
            $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#header").removeClass("hover");
        $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
    });

$(".guess_box").hover(function(){
    //This is the mouseenter event handler
    $(this).addClass("my_hover");
},
function(){
    //this is the mouseleav event handel
    $(this).removeClass("my_hover");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing way to much to actually get what you want. This is a proper way to do it:
I also added the "hover" effect on the header that you want. Don't use .hover, that's deprecated (not in use anymore). Instead use "`$('#yourdiv").on('mouseenter', yourfunctionname);` and `$('#yourdiv").on('mouseleave', yourfunctionname);`

Hopefully this helped. ;) Please ask if you need more answers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#header").addClass("hover");
        $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#header").removeClass("hover");
        $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
    });

    $('#header').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $("#header").addClass("hover");
        $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
    });

    $('#header').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
        $("#header").removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```